# UDP протокол ?

Tags: пакет, udp

у меня вопрос по доставке UDP пакетов: я так понимаю при передаче они могут теряться и вообще не дойти ?

Comment: Совершенно верно. А также могут дойти в неправильном порядке (если послан несколько). Протокол с ненадёжной доставкой пакетов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теоретически, да.

Сейчас (XXI век) в нормальной сети (тем более в локалке) практически не теряются (и не искажаются).

Другой вопрос потеря пакета из-за загруженности ОС (очередь IP порта приемника или вообще недостаток буферов в системе обмена по сети). Это возможно, UDP пакет, принятый сетевым драйвером может быть отброшен без уведомлений кого-либо (только в статистику попадет).